# Cardinality of all non-increasing functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, integers

Let $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ be a non-increasing function
(which means $x\leq y\implies g(x)\geq g(y)\ \forall x,y\in \mathbb N$).

I'm interested in the cardinality of the set which contains all such functions like $g$. My educated guess would be that this set is countable, but how can I prove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given such $g$, let $m=\min\{\,g(n)\mid n\in\Bbb N,\}$ and $n_0=\min\{\,n\in\Bbb N\mid g(n)=m\,\}$. Then $g(n)=m$ for all $n\ge n_0$ and  we see that $g$ is essentially given by the finite sequence $g(0),\ldots, g(n_0)$. The set of finite sequences of natural numbers is well-known to be countable.

Comment: Since we are working with decreasing functions of finite support here, we can even give a neat explicit bijection with $\mathbb{N}$: map $(g_1,\dots,g_n)$ to $\prod_{j=1}^{n}\pi_{g_j}$, where $\pi_{k}$ is the $k$th prime number

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen. Thank you, a beautiful and clear Argument! But why is the function given by a finite sequence ? There are domain of g is infinit so actually the sequence should be $g(0), ..., g(n_0) .... , g(n_0)$ with infinit  times $ g(n_0)$?